# Check if value exists in multiple tables

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have such tables in my database like `Customer`, `Member`, `Instructor`, `Employee` etc. Each of these users has his email adrress. I need to check if there is already a user with given email. I was thinking about:

- Check each table, something like this:

```cs
    public bool IsEmailAddressExists(string email)
    {
        if (!Context.Customers.Any(c => string.Equals(c.Email, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            if (!Context.Members.Any(m => string.Equals(m.Email, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
              ...
    }
```

- Select all emails and check:

```cs
    public bool IsEmailAddressExists(string email)
    {
        var emails = Context.Customers.Select(c => c.Email).Union(Context.Members.Select(m => m.Email))...; //other unions
        return emails.Any(e => string.Equals(e, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
```

There are more tables and many users, so I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to implement such kind of checking.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do the `select`, the `any` will be more efficient. But I cant see much more options for you as you need to search each table. Maybe you could do the same as a stored procedure if you really need that extra bit of performance. Alternative would be to maybe store all email addresses in a single table and link them up with relationships (much more work though)

Comment: @musefan, thanks for your answer. I thought about both options. I will think about stored procedure, and as for individual email table - I am not allowed to change database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure SQL this would be your most efficient because it stops searching as soon as it hits a match:

... As a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmailExists 
    @email varchar(254) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @emailExists bit

    SET @emailExists = 0

    SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE email = @email)
    IF @emailExists = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Member WHERE email = @email)
        IF @emailExists = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Instructor WHERE email = @email)
            IF @emailExists = 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Employee WHERE email = @email)
            END
        END
    END

    SELECT @emailExists
END
```

... As a scalar-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION EmailExists 
(
    @email varchar(254)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @emailExists bit

    SET @emailExists = 0

    SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE email = @email)
    IF @emailExists = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Member WHERE email = @email)
        IF @emailExists = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Instructor WHERE email = @email)
            IF @emailExists = 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @emailExists = 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Employee WHERE email = @email)
            END
        END
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @emailExists
END
```

In C# with Linq, you can use the Any extension and the || operator. Since Any usually gets translated to EXISTS in SQL and evalutation of the || operator in C# is lazy, evaluation will stop as soon as the first ocurrence of an email is reached.

```
bool emailExists = customerEmails.Any(e => string.Equals(e, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   || memberEmails.Any(e => string.Equals(e, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   || instructorEmails.Any(e => string.Equals(e, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                   || employeeEmails.Any(e => string.Equals(e, email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks JamieSee. I will use the second approach as for now, but probably create a `FUNCTION` in the future.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have a couple of options.

**Create a view.**  You could create a view in the database that shows, say, email addresses only.  Assuming you're using MSSQL Server, something like:

```
CREATE VIEW EmailView AS
SELECT Email from Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT Email from Instructors
....
```

... then using an entity bound to that view so you can check the list of emails to see if that email exists already.  Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more information.

**Normalize your database.**  Do each of these tables share common information beyond email, say, first name and/or last name?  It might be worth your time to reorganize your data model to put that information in a "Persons" table, then foreign key your other tables to it.  (This will also help if your users are two different things, say, a customer and an instructor.)

Comment: Bah, it's pre-coffee- you could also use a stored procedure to produce a bit result.

Comment: Thanks Ross. Yes, there are a common information like a first and last name, but as I said above I can't change the database schema.